# SciChart ITickProvder.Init method is never called

Tags: scichart

I'm setting a custom ITickProvider on a NumericAxis:

```cs
 var yaxis = new NumericAxis();
 yaxis.TickProvider = new MyTickProvider();
```

At runtime the ITickProvider.Init method is never called:

```cs
   public class MyTickProvider : ITickProvider
   {
      public void Init(IAxis axis)
      {
         // never called
      }

      public double[] GetMajorTicks(IAxisParams axis)
      {
         // this method is called first
         return new double[] {};
      }

      public double[] GetMinorTicks(IAxisParams axis)
      {
         // this method is called second
         return new double[] { };
      }
   }
```

What do I need to do so that Init is called? I'm using version 3.1.0.5013 of SciChart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in a recent [release (v3.1.0.5067)](http://www.scichart.com/category/releases/).